# What does the blue dot in the notification center indicate?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

If I send an APN to the device for my app, then when it appears in the notification center it has a blue dot to its left.

Does this signify anything? If so what? (If the notification is selected to launch the app then afterwards the dot is still there and is still blue, so if its supposed to indicate something like a read status its not working.)